# Disconnects all my clients suddenly -> Warning: Received PUBREL from <client-id> for an unknown packet identifier 247

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

```
Warning: Received PUBREL from 14444141 for an unknown packet identifier 247.
Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
```

Setup
A-Broker

```
max_inflight_messages 50000
max_queued_messages 10000
port 1883
persistence true
persistence_file mosquitto.db
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/
log_dest syslog
log_dest stdout
log_dest topic
log_dest stderr
connection_messages true
log_timestamp true
allow_anonymous true
log_timestamp true
# bridge
connection ToMQTTClassic123
address <ip>:1883
start_type automatic
topic # both 2 SAMPLE/ SAMPLE/
```

How do mitigate this issue, my broker seems to disconnects its clients suddenly I dont know why?

Im currently using mqtt v 1.4.10 for the broker
And currently using mqtt v1.1.0 for the client paho

**PS: All our clients used QOS2 with fixed client id when connecting to the broker.**

Comment: What client are you using, how many tones have you seen this, is there more log showing all the clients being disconnected?

Comment: im using paho for client. Logs have been so frequent now we have to migrate our broker to another ip address and isolate this defective broker. I also post my issue [here github](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/374).

Comment: @hardillb is there a way i can remove all pack identifier for these current client id or all of them for me its ok to remove them because we have our own offline mechanism workflow.

Comment: @hardillb does setting store_clean_interval to 0 fixed the issue of `Warning: Received PUBREL from 14444141 for an unknown packet identifier 247.`? i really need your help